# doing a REST PUT in PHP

Tags: php, json, rest, file-get-contents, put

I hope my question will be understood, my english is a not so good.

I'm nearly new with PHP and I just discovered REST APIs: I'm trying to use a REST API from my PHP script. Docs for the API can be found [here](http://api.ecwid.com/#update-a-product)

My final goal is to get a single product from this webservice and update it by adding the wholesalePrices array.

I've already managed to perform a GET request using file_get_contents(), in order to get the product ID i want to update. Now I have such id but can't understand how to perform the PUT request: as far I can understand, there are mainly two ways to do REST calls in PHP: one with file_get_contents, another by using cURL.

Since I used file_get_contents for my GET request, I continued with this approach, but my code:

```
$wholesalePrices = json_encode($wholesalePrices);
$dataRAW = array(
                  "wholesalePrices" => $wholesalePrices 
                );
$dataToPut = http_build_query($dataRAW);
$context = [
              'http' => [
                          'method' => 'PUT',
                          'header' =>  "Authorization: apikeystring\r\n" . "Content-Length: " . strlen($dataToPut) . "\r\n" . "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
                          'content' => $dataToPut
                        ]                             
           ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$url = "https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/xxxxxxx/products/".urlencode($productId)."?token=".urlencode(myToken);   
$result = file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);
```

returns a PHP warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/xxxxxxxxx/products/xxxxxxxxx?token=xxxxxxxxxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Wrong JSON format: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1] in upload.php on line 95

var_dumping $wholesalePrices just after the json_encode() results in

> string '[{"quantity":1,"price":0},{"quantity":5,"price":6},{"quantity":25,"price":12},{"quantity":100,"price":25}]' (length=106)

where am I wrong?

---

ok, I tried using RamRaider approach and now my code is this

```
$data = json_encode(array('wholesalePrices' => $wholesalePrices)/*, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT*/);
          $dataRAW = array(
                            "wholesalePrices" => $wholesalePrices 
                     );      
          $dataToPut = $dataRAW;
          $dataToPut = http_build_query($dataRAW);
$context = array('http' => array('method'    =>  'PUT',
                           'header'    =>  "Authorization: apikeystring\r\nContent-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n",
                           'content'   =>  $data));

          $context = stream_context_create($context);
          $url = "https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/".urlencode(MY_STORE_ID)."/products/".urlencode($productId)."?token=".urlencode(MY_TOKEN);   
$result = file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);
```

But I obtain a `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Field Product.wholesalePrices should be an array` message.
If I comment the `, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` instead, the HTTP message becomes  `409 Conflict` and it refers at the line with `$result = file_get_contents ($url, false, $context);` so perhaps I am on the right track, but how can I troubleshoot such error?

---

ok, done some mods: now - after the json_encode() - my dataToPut (which I put in "Content" in the HTTP request) var_dumps as following (WPPair is a class I specifically created to reproduce the format required):

```
object(stdClass)[3]
  public 'wholesalePrices' => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => 
        object(WPpair)[5]
          public 'quantity' => int 5
          public 'price' => int 6
      2 => 
        object(WPpair)[4]
          public 'quantity' => int 25
          public 'price' => int 12
      3 => 
        object(WPpair)[6]
          public 'quantity' => int 100
          public 'price' => int 25
```

so I think it has to be right for the api. But I still get a HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

---

Ok, finally I managed to form a (perhaps) right structure for my JSON, all the more so as Postman validates my dataToPut with an HTTP

> 200 OK

And my test record results updated.
This is the print_r() output on dataToPut after json_encode():

> string
>   '{"id":56782231,"wholesalePrices":[{"quantity":5,"price":5.64},{"quantity":25,"price":5.28},{"quantity":100,"price":4.5}]}'
>   (length=121)

However, if I try to send the same JSON from my PHP page, I still get a

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

and in fact, my records still aren't updated.

Here's my code:

```
$dataToPut = $dataRAW;
$dataRAW = http_build_query($dataRAW);
$context = [
            'http' => [
                       'method' => 'PUT',
                       'header' =>  "Authorization: apikeystring\r\n" . "Content-Length: ".sizeof($dataToPut)."\r\n" . "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
                       'content' => $dataToPut
                      ]                             
           ];
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$url = "https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/xxxxxxx/products/".urlencode($productId)."?token=".urlencode(myToken);
$dataToPut = json_encode($dataToPut);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Where am I wrong this time?

---

After rewriting my code by using cURL instead of file_get_contents to connect to the API, I managed to get it to work.
Now the API call part looks like this:

```
      $dataToPut = $dataRAW;
      $dataRAW = http_build_query($dataRAW);
      $context = [
                    'http' => [
                                'method' => 'PUT',
                                'header' =>  "Authorization: apikeystring\r\n" . "Content-Length: ".sizeof($dataToPut)."\r\n" . "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
                                'content' => $dataToPut
                              ]                             
                 ];
      $context = stream_context_create($context);


      $url = "https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/xxxxxxx/products/".urlencode($productId)."?token=".urlencode($myToken);
      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: app.ecwid.com','Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8','Cache-Control: no-cache'));
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataToPut);

      // Make the REST call, returning the result
      $response = curl_exec($curl);
      echo ($response."<br/>");
      if (!$response) {
        echo("Connection Failure: ".curl_error($curl));
        die();
      }
      curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: try adding the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option to the `json_encode` function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the documentation for their api I might be leading you astray but the error message does suggest that their api expects json data whereas you encode the data and then add to an array which seems back to front somehow.

```
$data = json_encode( array( 'wholesalePrices' => $wholesalePrices  ), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );

/* Perhaps this also is not required */
#$data = http_build_query( $data );

$context = array(
    'http' => array(
            'method'    =>  'PUT',
            'header'    =>  "Authorization: apikeystring\r\nContent-Length: " . strlen( $data ) . "\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n",
            'content'   =>  $data
        )                             
    );

$context = stream_context_create( $context );
$url = "https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/7560546/products/".urlencode( $productId )."?token=".urlencode( myToken );   
$result = file_get_contents( $url, false, $context );
```

Having had a quick look at the api documentation I found the following:

> PUT https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/{storeId}/products/{productId}?token={token}
>
> ### Request body
>
> A JSON object of type 'Product’ with the following fields:

```
wholesalePrices -> Array<WholesalePrice>
 described as: "Sorted array of wholesale price tiers (quantity limit and price pairs)"
```

### The given example request to update a product is:

```
PUT /api/v3/4870020/products/39766764?token=123456789abcd HTTP/1.1
Host: app.ecwid.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "compareToPrice": 24.99,
  "categoryIds": [
    9691094
  ]
}
```

So using test data

```
        $wholesalePrices=array(
            array('quantity'=>10,'price'=>1000),
            array('quantity'=>2,'price'=>43),
            array('quantity'=>43,'price'=>34),
            array('quantity'=>7,'price'=>5),
            array('quantity'=>9,'price'=>63),
        );
        $data = json_encode( array( 'wholesalePrices' => $wholesalePrices  ) );
        echo '<pre>',$data,'</pre>';
```

Gives data in the format:

```
{
    "wholesalePrices":[
        {"quantity":10,"price":1000},
        {"quantity":2,"price":43},
        {"quantity":43,"price":34},
        {"quantity":7,"price":5},
        {"quantity":9,"price":63}
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you please check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357141/error-updating-the-details-using-rest-api